# Populate select options under schema settings dynamically from external source in Shopify app

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-app-extension

```
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "test-field",
  "target": "section",
  "class": "testClass",
  "tag": "section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "test_id",
      "label": "Test Field",
      "info": "An option for informational text about the test field",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "test_value_1",
          "label": "Test Value 1"
        },
        {
          "value": "test_value_2",
          "label": "Test Value 2"
        },
        {
          "value": "test_value_3",
          "label": "Test Value 3"
        }
      ]
    },
    { 
      "type": "color", 
      "id": "colour", 
      "label": "Star Colour", 
      "default": "#000" 
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Is there any way I can populate Select Options ( under schema>settings ) dynamically from external source in Shopify App Extension? Is there any way populating the options without metafields?